# Sending Multiple Information from BNO055 IMU to BridgeClient on Yun

Tags: arduino-yun

I have an **Arduino Yun** which is interfaces via **I2C** to a Adafruit BNO055 breakout board.

My Aim is to use **Python Flask** in conjunction with **BridgeServer** and **BridgeClient** to obtain the Sensor Information from the **ATmega32u4** microcontroller to the Microprocessor and use **HTML5 Server Side Event (SSE)** to display live sensor information on Network interfaces.

I would like to show the Euler angles and Linear Acceleration values:

1. heading
2. pitch
3. roll
4. linear_accerlation_x
5. linear_acceleration_y
6. linear_acceleration_z

An Example of similar concept can be obtained from [Smart Measuring Cup by Adafruit](https://github.com/tdicola/SmartMeasuringCup). However, in the code sketch the user sends only one value :

```
BridgeClient client;
....
client.println(volume, 5);
```

And at the **Python Flask** end the code opens up a socket and uses `makefile()` method to read value

```
def yunserver_sse():
    try:
        # Connect to YunServer instance that's listening on localhost.
        soc = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 5678))
        socfile = soc.makefile()
        while True:
            # Get data from server.
            line = socfile.readline()
            # Stop if the server closed the connection.
            if not line:
                raise StopIteration
            # Send the data to the web page in the server sent event format.
            yield 'data: {0}\n\n'.format(line)
            # Sleep so the CPU isn't consumed by this thread.
            time.sleep(0)
    except socket.error:
        # Error connecting to socket. Raise StopIteration to quit.
raise StopIteration
```

Instead of sending just *one* measured parameter how can I send all above mentioned 6 at the same time?

**note**

I tried using **ArduinoJson** library but I find it difficult to parse the JSON on the Python Flask end as `readline()` expects a `\n` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution to my problem was a simple `client.println()` after my JSON was ready to be printed to the **BridgeClient**.

**Snippet**:

```
root.printTo(client); client.println();
```

where `root` is `DynamicJsonBuffer` from the **ArduinoJson** library. The `client.println()` would immediately print `\n` and this would be read by the `readline()` python code.